# shiro integrate spring with servlet3.1, tomcat can not start

Tags: shiro, spring-4, servlet-3.1

**shiro config**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.butler.service" })
public class SpringShiroConfig {
@Bean
public EhCacheManager ehCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManager ehCacheManager = new EhCacheManager();
    ehCacheManager.setCacheManagerConfigFile("classpath:ehcache.xml");
    return ehCacheManager;
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcUserRealm")
public JdbcUserRealm jdbcUserRealm() {
    return new JdbcUserRealm();
}

@Bean(name = "securityManager")
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(@Qualifier("jdbcUserRealm") Realm jdbcUserRealm) {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    securityManager.setRealm(jdbcUserRealm);
    return securityManager;
}

@Bean(name = "formAuthenticationFilter")
public FormAuthenticationFilter formAuthenticationFilter() {
    FormAuthenticationFilter filter = new FormAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setLoginUrl("/admin/login");
    return filter;
}

@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean(
        @Qualifier("securityManager")SecurityManager securityManager,
        @Qualifier("formAuthenticationFilter")FormAuthenticationFilter filter) {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/admin/login");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/admin/main");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("admin/unauthorized");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitions(
        "/admin/login = anon\n" +
        "/admin/logout = logout\n" +
        "/admin* = authc" +
        "/resources* = anon\n"
    );

    //filters
    Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
    filters.put("authc", filter);

    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilters(filters);

    return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
}
```

**servlet container initial**

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {
        SpringShiroConfig.class
    };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {
        SpringWebConfig.class
    };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/"};
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic shiroFilter = servletContext.addFilter("shiroFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    shiroFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
    shiroFilter.setInitParameter("targetFilterLifecycle", "true");
}
```

**spring mvc config**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.web" })
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

when start tomcat spring container initial error.

```
2016-03-06 22:16:09
[INFO]-[Thread: RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]-[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext()]: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 18283 ms
06-Mar-2016 22:16:09.541 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
 06-Mar-2016 22:16:09.541 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors

2016-03-06 22:16:09
[INFO]-[Thread: RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1]-[org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose()]: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Mar 06 22:15:52 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2016-03-06 10:16:09,665] Artifact admin:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    06-Mar-2016 23:36:03.673 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.butler.web.WebAppI
nitializer@4ec2d825]
06-Mar-2016 23:36:07.418 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
06-Mar-2016 23:36:26.201 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter shiroFilter
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shiroFilter': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgu
mentException: There is no filter with name 'authc/resources* = anon' to apply to chain [/admin*] in the pool of available Filters.  Ensure a filter with that name/path has first been register
ed with the addFilter method(s).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1590)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1678)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
```

if the `WebAppInitializer` is not overwrited `onStartup` to add `shiroFilter`  tomcat server can start normal, I don't know what problem in my code.

the filter using web.xml has the same problem.(spring and shiro use java config)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: It says: `Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file` and `See server log for details`, so perhaps you can find more information there and post that as well?

Comment: but can not find out more log.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand that. Do you mean you can't find the log files? Or that you don't understand the log files?

Comment: add log detail in the question.

Comment: I find it. There is no filter with name 'authc/resources* = anon'

Comment: thank you, Carpetsmoker.

Comment: `       
     shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitions(
            "/admin/login = anon\n" +
            "/admin/logout = logout\n" +
            "/admin* = authc\n" +
            "/resources* = anon\n"
        );
`